# Hindi font is visible when I am running JFrame program from Netbeans but not visible when running .jar file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts, executable-jar

I am using Hindi fonts in my project and when I am running it on Netbeans it works fine, but when I am run its .jar file it does not load Hindi font, but shows some garbage things.
I am using UTF-8 encoding in Netbeans, and Arial Unicode MS font.

When running from Netbeans:

[image: When running from Netbeans]

When running .jar file:

[image: When running .jar file]

There are no issues in English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which calls `Font.createFont`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: *I am using UTF-8 encoding in Netbeans*: And which encoding do you use when running the .jar file? Probably not UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: how do I use utf-8 when runninh .jar file

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem, it was happening because I was using UTF-8 in NetBeans, but .jar file was using some other encoding. So when reading the file I gave CharSet UTF-8.

```
List<String> s=  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(langPath + "\\" + ExcerciseList.getSelectedValue() + ".txt"),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Can you explain this in detail? if I have to convert only one filed of the database into Hindi font then what should I do?